# function don't append element data1 or data2 (python inheritance)

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to reach added data1 array but when i started py file the result of data1 is null array.
Also i've tried is that to call drawit function in def **init** in this time py file is not giving me any result

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


arduino = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600,timeout=.1)

class serial_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data1=[]
        self.data2=[]

    def drawit(self):
        while True:
            while (arduino.inWaiting() == 0):
                pass
            data = arduino.readline().decode('UTF-8')[:-2]
            tempdata = data.split(",")
            self.data1.append(tempdata[0])
            self.data2.append(tempdata[1])


print(serial_class().data1)
```

Comment: The reason `drawit()` function is not returning any result is that it gets stuck in the `while True:` loop. You have to break from it.

Comment: it doesn't matter. Could you write code. I could not do it ```class serial_class():
 def __init__(self):
  self.data1=[]
  self.data2=[]
  self.drawit()
  
 def drawit(self):
  while True:
   while (arduino.inWaiting() == 0):
    pass
   data = arduino.readline().decode('UTF-8')[:-2]
   tempdata = data.split(",")
   self.data1.append(tempdata[0])
   self.data2.append(tempdata[1])
  return self.data1,self.data2
```

Comment: Also, you never call drawit()

Comment: Once you pass `while (arduino.inWaiting() == 0):` is all data prepared for you? Or you have a stream of data coming in?

Answer (score 0):

Your `drawit` is a infinite loop blocking function, hence you will never be able to access its data once from the main processe once started.

I suggest you to use threads:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time


data_1 = []
stop_it = False


def threaded_collector():
  global stop_it 
  i = 0
  while True:
    if stop_it:
        break
    # collect your Arduino data here
    data_1.append(i)
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)


collect_data_thread = Thread(target=threaded_collector)
collect_data_thread.start()

# do you computations here
print(data_1)
time.sleep(5)
print(data_1)

# kill the thread and exit the program
stop_it = True
collect_data_thread.join()
```

Comment: thank you so much. Those codes are working but they are not working with classes. It gives me null array as it was before

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need a class? To work with classes see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm